# express.js css not loading but html does

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, npm

[folder and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdYAy.png)
server.js this is what i created so far

```
//importing packages
const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const path = require('path');

//declare static path
let staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "js");

//intializing express.js

const app = express();

//midlewares
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

//routes
//home route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "index.html"));
})

//signup route
app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "signup.html"));
})

// 404 route
app.get("/404", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "404.html"));
})

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/404');
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000.......');
})
```

index.html this is what i created so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edga">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Clothing - Best Apparels Online Store</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar"></nav>

        <!-- hero section-->

        <header class="hero-section">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="../img/light-logo.png" class="logo" alt="">
                <p class="sub-heading">best fashion collection of all time</p>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- card-container-->

        <section class="product">
            <h2 class="product-category">best selling</h2>
            <button class="pre-btn"><img src="../img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
            <button class="nxt-btn"><img src="../img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
            <div class="product-container">
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card1.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card2.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card3.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card4.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card5.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card6.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card7.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card8.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- collections -->

        <section class="collection-container">
            <a href="#" class="collection">
                <img src="../img/women-collection.png" alt="">
                <p class="collection-title">women <br> apparels </p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="collection">
                <img src="../img/men-collection.png" alt="">
                <p class="collection-title">women <br> apparels </p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="collection">
                <img src="../img/accessories-collection.png" alt="">
                <p class="collection-title">accessories</p>
            </a>
        </section>
        
        <!-- card-container-->

        <section class="product">
            <h2 class="product-category">Shirts</h2>
            <button class="pre-btn"><img src="../img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
            <button class="nxt-btn"><img src="../img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
            <div class="product-container">
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/product image 1.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/product image 2.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/product image 3.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/product image 4.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card5.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card6.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card7.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card8.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- card-container-->

        <section class="product">
            <h2 class="product-category">Shoes</h2>
            <button class="pre-btn"><img src="../img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
            <button class="nxt-btn"><img src="../img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
            <div class="product-container">
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card9.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card10.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card11.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card12.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card5.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card6.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card7.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <span class="discount-tag">50% off</span>
                        <img src="../img/card8.png" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                        <button class="card-btn">add to wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h2 class="product-brand">brand</h2>
                        <p class="product-short-des">a short line about the cloth...</p>
                        <span class="price">$20</span><span class="actual-price">$40</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer>
            
        </footer>

        <script src="../js/nav.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/home.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/footer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i run localhost:3000 html does load but css doesnt
what should i do?
i am doing trying to recreate tutorial, but the author doesnt have this problem, nor somebody in the comments, this is the link of the creator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYSfOe0QBOk&list=PLqm86YkewF6S45smPYeNv01aFFKWZSgYD&index=2&ab_channel=ModernWeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory that you declare as static with `app.use(express.static(staticPath));` shouldn't be the `js` directory. You'd better create a directory like `public` in which you move your `css` and `js` directories.

After that, your url for your css files will be `/css/xxxx.css` and for your js files `/js/xxxx.js`

Let us know ^^

Comment: Thank you, my savior, i fixed it :D fixed url wih Css and Js and changet server.js like this
let staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "public");

//midlewares

app.use(express.static(staticPath));

//routes
//home route

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "js", "index.html"));
})

Comment: Cool, have a nice trip with your tutorial ^^